# Onclick of the button move to the next tab of vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

If I click on the button which is placed in the content of the first tab then I want to move to the next tab. how can I do this??

Tab:

```
<v-tabs
  color="cyan"
  dark
  slider-color="yellow"
>
  <v-tab ripple>
    Item 1
  </v-tab>
  <v-tab ripple>
    Item 2
  </v-tab>
  <v-tab-item>
    <v-card flat>
      <v-btn @click="changeTab()">
    </v-card>
  </v-tab-item>
  <v-tab-item>
    <v-card flat>
      <v-card-text>Contents for Item 2 go here</v-card-text>
    </v-card>
  </v-tab-item>  
</v-tabs>
```

Method:

```
changeTab(){
   console.log('hello')
}
```

Comment: What is `v-tab` what library are you using ?

Comment: @PierreSaid vuetify library

Comment: @VarinderSohal You can use vuetify stepper component to achieve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `v-model` and `value` and in your `changeTab` method just change the value of the bound variable. The working code snippet is below:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  methods:{
    changeTab(){
     this.tab='tab-2'
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      tab: 'tab-1'
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.1.9/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.1.9/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>


<div id="app">
 <v-tabs
  v-model='tab'
  color="cyan"
  dark
  slider-color="yellow"
>
  <v-tab ripple href='#tab-1'>
    Item 1
  </v-tab>
  <v-tab ripple href='#tab-2'>
    Item 2
  </v-tab>
  <v-tab-item value='tab-1'> 
    <v-card flat>
      <v-btn @click="changeTab()">Go to item2</v-btn>
    </v-card>
  </v-tab-item>
  <v-tab-item value='tab-2'>
    <v-card flat>
      <v-card-text>Contents for Item 2 go here</v-card-text>
    </v-card> 
  </v-tab-item>  
</v-tabs>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Lana, this works like a charm. Well, we didn't get the idea of the v-model. You seem to be an expert in vuetify and vuejs, and we are beginners so would you like to help us in our critical situation with vuejs, are you on discord or something so we can be in touch.? and thanks once again.